# Data not aligned correctly in Visual Studio if run in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, alignment, sse

I've been working with SSE for a while now, and I've seen my share of alignment issues. This, however, is beyond my understanding:

> I get different alignment whether I
>   run the program using F5 (debug) or
>   whether I run it outside the debugger
>   (Ctrl+F5)!

Some background info:
I'm using a wrapper for a SSE-enabled datatype - with overloaded operators and custom allocator (overloaded`new` and `delete` operators using `_mm_malloc` and `_mm_free`). But in the example below, I've managed to reduce to problem even further, i.e. the issue also happens even if I don't use the custom allocator.

As you can see below, in main() I dynamically allocate a TestClass object on the heap, which contains a SSEVector type object. I'm using a dummy `float[2]` member variable to "missalign" the stack a bit.

I obtain the following output when I run with F5:

```
object address 00346678
_memberVariable1 address 00346678
_sseVector address 00346688
```

And if I run with Ctrl+F5:

```
object address 00345B70
_memberVariable1 address 00345B70
_sseVector address 00345B80
```

As you can see, the alignment is different (i.e. not 16-byte) when I run it in the debugger. Is it just a coincidence that the alignment is correct when using Ctrl-F5? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with a new project (default settings).

If I declare the object on the stack, i.e. `TestClass myObject;`, this issue does not appear. Using `__declspec(align(16))` does not help, either.

The code I used to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <xmmintrin.h>  // SSE
//#include "DynAlignedAllocator.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class SSEVector /*: public DynAlignedAllocator<16>*/
{
public:
    SSEVector() { }

    __m128 vec;
};

class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass() { }

    /*__declspec(align(16))*/ float _memberVariable1 [2];
    SSEVector _sseVector;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main (void)
{
    TestClass* myObject = new TestClass;

    std::cout << "object address " << myObject << std::endl;
    std::cout << "_memberVariable1 address " << &(myObject->_memberVariable1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "_sseVector address " << &(myObject->_sseVector) << std::endl;

    delete myObject;

    // wait for ENTER
    std::string dummy;
    std::getline(std::cin, dummy);

    return 0;
}
```

Any hints or commentaries are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue for `__declspec( align( numBytes ) ) float` where `numBytes > 128` though MS says it can be up to 8192 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx. How did you solve it? It happens only in Debug Mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running under the debugger, you're using the debug heap, which may affect alignment.

Set `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` in your environment settings, and see if this helps.

See e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366705%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

However, alignment is not guaranteed when allocating with malloc or new. The "correct" way of solving this in VS is to use `_aligned_malloc`.

When you want your SSEVector as a member of another structure, you need to change the *packing* of this structure (using #pragma pack), or the __declspec(align) of SSEVector.

See [How align works with data packing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vclrfhowalignworkswithdatapacking)

What happens in your cases are (apart from the seemingly coincidental debugger/non-debugger difference):

`SSEVector` is declared unaligned. If you allocate it directly using `_aligned_malloc`, it'll be aligned. `TestClass` is also unaligned, and uses default packing. If you allocate it using `_aligned_malloc`, the `TestClass` instance will be properly aligned. This doesn't help you at all, since you want the `SSEVector` *member variable* to be aligned.

Adding an alignment requirement on `SSEVector` using `__declspec(align)` will tell the compiler that `SSEVector` stack variables must be aligned, *and* that `SSEVector` as a struct member must be aligned *within the struct/class*. Now, if you allocate a `TestClass` using `_aligned_malloc`, it will be properly aligned. And the `SSEVector` offset in the struct is also properly aligned due to the declspec, so the absolute address of the SSEVector will be correct for your use.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that... but unfortunately, it didn't change the alignment. I'm still getting a 8-byte offset for the variables when I run it in the debugger.

Comment: Yeah, there's no alignment guarantee. Odds are this is simply a coincidence, but I cannot prove that :). If you just want to *fix* it, use _aligned_malloc.

Comment: I've tried using _aligned_malloc and _mm_malloc (By inheritance in SSEVector class:  DynAlignedAllocator<16>)
DynAlignedAllocator contains overloaded new and delete operators.. but this doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Updated answer - #pragma pack(16) before TestClass, or __declspec(align(16)) on SSEVector, combined with _aligned_malloc, should fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. On my machine, neither __declspec(align(16)) in front of the SSEVector declaration nor #pragma pack(16) help :-( I've also tried /Zp16, which should do the same as the pack(16), but globally, right?

Comment: Yep. Note that you need to *also* use _aligned_malloc, just aligning/packing won't help you.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed your last edit. :-)
The last paragraph definitely clears things up for me!

Comment: Woohoo! It's properly aligned now. I did a public inheritance of DynAlignedAllocator<16> for the TestClass, which corresponds to using _aligned_malloc.

I guess the real problem was my understanding of what which alignment directive did, i.e. members within the class vs. the class itself.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: np, have fun, and look forward to fighting with shader data alignment ;)